# Transaction propagation from stateless session bean to stateful session bean

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

If a stateless session bean, message-driven bean, or stateful session bean with a transaction-scoped persistence context calls a stateful session bean with an extended persistence context in the same JTA transaction, an IllegalStateException is thrown.

Could someone explain the behaviour.
Should'nt the container suspend the transaction of the stateless session bean until the method of stateful session bean returns and then resume the transaction.

Comment: Could you provide some example code or link to doc reference from where this behaviour is obtained?

Comment: @Andremoniy: came across it in JPA specs

Comment: Be more specific: provide the link

Comment: Hibernate https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Hibernate_EntityManager_User_Guide/sect-Hibernate_EntityManager_User_Guide-EJB_container_environment-Persistence_context_propagation.html                                JPA spec:https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/